# Ignore view validation when element has attributes `display: none`

Tags: javascript, html, .net

I have the following html text input that will show/hide using jQuery's `slideUp` and `slideDown` that essentially will set display attribute to none but with animation. The issue I am facing is that I don't want to validate when element has attribute `display: none`. Is it possible to do in view (or MVC), without JavaScript?

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.HomeNumber, new { required = "", pattern = ".{3,}" })
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about this?

```
.slideUp('slow', function(){
    $('#HomeNumber').removeAttr('required');
});

.slideDown('slow', function(){
    $('#HomeNumber').attr('required');
});
```